# How to get laravel transport email username with failover

Tags: laravel

i have setup 2 smtp mailers:

```
'smtp' => [
     'transport' => 'smtp',
     'host' => smtp.gmail.org,
     'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
     'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
     'username' => 'smtp1@gmail.com',
     'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
     'timeout' => null,
     'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
],
'smtp-1' => [
     'transport' => 'smtp',
     'host' => smtp.gmail.org,
     'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
     'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
     'username' => 'smtp2@gmail.com',
     'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
     'timeout' => null,
     'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
],
```

and set failover:

```
'failover' => [
            'transport' => 'failover',
            'mailers' => [
                'smtp'   
                'smtp-1'
            ],
        ],
```

the setup was was run fine.

```
$transport = $Mail::raw($message, function($msg) use ($to, $subject) {
            $msg->to($to)->subject($subject);
        });
```

the problem how can i get the actual sender mailer, since it can failed and swith to other mailer?

i try to get the return path with:

```
$header = $transport->getOriginalMessage();
$sender = $header->getReturnPath();
dd($sender);
```

but it return `null`;

i expect to get either `smtp1@gmail.com` or `smtp2@gmail.com`